# Dynamic Picklist for lightning-combobox

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, picklist, salesforce-id

community. I got a question about two custom fields with type Picklists and `lightning-combobox`.
Suppose combobox 1 shows Picklist 1 value while combobox 2 shows Picklist 2 value.

```
<template>
   <lightning-combobox label="Picklist 1" options={optionSet1}></lightning-combobox>
   <lightning-combobox label="Picklist 2" options={optionSet2}></lightning-combobox>
</template>
```

I used the following javascript to fetch the picklist values.

```
@track optionSet1

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CUSTOM_OBJECT })
objectInfo;

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId', fieldApiName: FIELD_1 })
getPicklistValues({error, data}) {
   if (data) {
      this.optionSet1 = data.values.map(plValue => {
         return {
            label: plValue.label,
            value: plValue.value
         }
   });
}
```

---

***Updates from 19 Aug:***
Thanks for the advice by @arut. With `getPicklistValuesByRecordType`, I can fetch all the picklist values of a object. Below is the code:
Javascript

```
options1;
options2;

@wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: CUSTOM_OBJECT })
    objectInfo;

    @wire(getPicklistValuesByRecordType, {objectApiName: CUSTOM_OBJECT, recordTypeId: '$objectInfo.data.defaultRecordTypeId' })
    picklistValues({data, error}) {
        if (data) {
            this.options1 = data.picklistFieldValues.Field_1__c.values;
            this.options2 = data.picklistFieldValues.Field_2__c.values;
        }
    }
```

Then, you can set them into the HTML like the one the developer doc describe.

Reference: [Build UI for Picklists](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_features_records_dependent_picklist.htm)
[getPicklistValuesByRecordType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values_record)

Comment: Can you add the exact code where the issue exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [getPicklistValuesByRecordType](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_picklist_values_record) instead of `getPicklistValues`. This will return a map of string vs picklist values (as [Picklist Values Collection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.uiapi.meta/uiapi/ui_api_responses_picklist_values_collection.htm)), which you can then parse and set both the combo-boxes in one go. This would also remove the additional apex server call.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It works. I will update with a working solution for people who have similar issues.